# Unregister Field from State

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview, flutter-form-builder

### Unregister Field from State

**7.7.0 version:**

### I am getting _fields.containsKey(name) after removing Text Field from a List

I have dynamic count of Cells (each cell contains one TextField) in my Scroll View, the User is also able to remove Cells.
After deleting cells and dismiss the screen, I think the disposer / deinit part is taking over and iterate each _field and tried to unregisterField.

**By doing that, I am getting:**

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
'package:flutter_form_builder/src/form_builder.dart': Failed assertion: line 194 pos 12: '_fields.containsKey(name)': is not true.

## Idea

I could not find any Documentation how I can unregister Fields by my self after removing the Cell, I can call `formKey.currentState?.unregisterField` but I don't know how I can get access to `FormBuilderFieldState`.

Any help?

SDK https://github.com/flutter-form-builder-ecosystem/flutter_form_builder

Answer (score 0):

FlutterFormBuilder rapresents field states in a map inside the `currentState`, you can access the currentState from the form key that you are using (the same state where you access the unregister function. This is an example

```dart
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();


final FormBuilderFieldState<FormBuilderField<dynamic>, dynamic> field = _formKey.currentState!.fields['[your_field]']!;

_formKey.currentState!.unregisterField('[your_field]', field);
```

Hope this answer can help you!